# TypeError: fetch.mockResponse is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch, enzyme

Running into the following error:
TypeError: fetch.mockResponse is not a function

Trying to test the following :

```
getRequests = () => {
  let headersObj = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':  this.props.services.Dashboard.subscription_key,
   }
  fetch(`${this.props.services.Dashboard.URL}/REQUEST`, {
    headers: headersObj,
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    if(json.value) {
      this.setState({Requests: json.value, allowNext: true})
   }
 })
}
```

Here is what I have so far: Not really sure if I am on the right path to test this correctly but I would appreciate any help, thanks

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><FileName {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>)


it('Test getRequests function ',() => {
  wrapper.find('FileName').setState({
    Requests: [],
    allowNext: true
    });

 fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify([]));
 wrapper.update();
 expect(wrapper.find('FileName').instance().getRequests('test')).toEqual()
 expect(wrapper.find('FileName').state('allowNext')).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Why do you think `fetch` would have a `mockResponse` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock api in jest and enzym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621873/how-to-mock-api-in-jest-and-enzym)

Comment: I was following this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576635/how-to-wait-in-enzyme-for-a-promise-from-a-private-function

Answer (score 3):

`mockResponse` isn't a built-in function in the Fetch API - it would appear you've followed an example that was using the [jest-mock-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) library that adds various mocking helper functions, including [mockResponse](https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock#mock-responses).

Comment: That was my first guess after I ran the code,  anything that I could do to improve and get this test to work ?

Comment: Well installing that library would be a start....are you saying you have already installed the library and it hasn't fixed the problem?

Comment: @usertestREACT read the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock#usage)...

Comment: @usertestREACT were you able to fix it?